# 18.04 -- Partition will no longer mount

Tags: partitioning

I have a dual boot but only use the Ubuntu.  One of my windows partitions I used to always use to download onto, all of a sudden won't mount.  Is there a way to have Ubuntu fix it?
thanks
OK. I go to the "Files" icon and select "other locations" and every partition I click on will mount.  this partition used to mount when I selected it, but now if just takes some time and then says "Unable to Access Location, volume not mounted".
All the others mount when clicked on.
I just tried the sudo mount and this is what I got
can't find in /etc/fstab.

Comment: Please elaborate upon what you are seeing. What leads you to conclude that the partition "won't mount"? Grinding noise? Error message? Flashing lights? Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1170796/edit) your question to include more information.

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to manually `sudo mount` it?

Comment: Best not to use NTFS with Linux unless dual booting. Most NTFS repairs like chkdsk or defrag can only be run from Windows or a Windows repair flash drive.

Comment: The reason I'm using Ubuntu is because my XP got messed up.  So I can't really run XP to fix it.   I just wondered if Ubuntu had an equivalent of chkdsk.